# JdbcChannelMessageStore performance issue on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-integration

I'm using SI 4.3.19 and we are having some performance issues with the message store on PostgreSQL, with 670.000 messages.

I search around and found this issue:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2629

but I found it was fixed on version 5.0.11 and 5.1.2.

Are there any plans to have a fix in 4.3.x also?

In case not, which changes do you recommend me to apply on a custom fix?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to make these changes on your PostgreSQL schema:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE INT_MESSAGE_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO CYCLE;

CREATE TABLE INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE (
    MESSAGE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    GROUP_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATED_DATE BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE_PRIORITY BIGINT,
    MESSAGE_SEQUENCE BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('INT_MESSAGE_SEQ'),
    MESSAGE_BYTES BYTEA,
    REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    constraint INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE_PK primary key (REGION, GROUP_KEY, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_SEQUENCE)
);

CREATE INDEX INT_CHANNEL_MSG_DELETE_IDX ON INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE (REGION, GROUP_KEY, MESSAGE_ID);
-- This is only needed if the message group store property 'priorityEnabled' is true
-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INT_CHANNEL_MSG_PRIORITY_IDX ON INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE (REGION, GROUP_KEY, MESSAGE_PRIORITY DESC, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_SEQUENCE);
```

This way you are going to have an optimized index without any changes into a Java code.

Comment: Thanks Artem! Just to confirm, the changes of size and order of sentences made in the pull request are not needed?

Comment: Let's hope it is not needed! We haven't expected someone else is stuck with Java 6 yet...